# Browser errors when echoing ajax in JavaScript using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to echo a list of links and ajax functions back to my page, so I can then load the desired text into the current page. But no matter what combination of single and double quotes I use I get `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -"` errors. Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
    $files = glob('*.txt');
    rsort($files);
    $arrlength = count($files);
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo $files[$x] . filesize($files[$x]);
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<a href='#' onclick='$files[$x]();'>Restore</a>";
    echo "<script>
            function $files[$x]() {
            $.get(\"toc/major/$files[$x]\", function(data) {
            $(\"#main-content\").html(data);
            });
            }
         </script>";
}
?>
```

Console details:

```
VM1965:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.js:2
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.domManip (jquery.js:3)
    at m.fn.init.append (jquery.js:3)
    at m.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.js:3)
    at m.access (jquery.js:3)
    at m.fn.init.html (jquery.js:3)
    at Object.success (mywritingplace.js:39)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
```

P.S. If I replace the ajax in the function with a simple JS alert, it all works fine.

Comment: that's a js error(?) so its not an issue with the php. past the rendered js. you don't need one js function per file.

Comment: Thanks @Dagon. What do you mean I don't just need one js function per file? That ajax function should load the text file into my main-content div right?

Comment: i suck at js, but you only need one function, you can pass the file name to it in the call `onclick='MyFileFunction($files[$x]);` then you have a single `MyFileFunction()`

Comment: Awesome...much better idea! I think the error may be because I have already used ajax to load the files into the div, and the `at Object.success (mywritingplace.js:39)` line refers to that function. Thanks for help narrowing it down, and for the the js code reduction